# Count single occurrences of a row item

Tags: sql, count

I would like to count the number of times an item in a column has appeared only once.  For example if in my table I had...

```
Name
----------
Fred
Barney   
Wilma
Fred
Betty
Barney
Fred
```

...it would return me a count of 2 because only Wilma and Betty have appeared once.

Comment: Which RDBMS? MySQL? SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Here is SQLFiddel Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fd119/2)**

**Below is the Query which you can try:**

```
select count(*) from 
(select Name 
  from Table1
 group by Name
having count(*) = 1) T
```

Till Above my post was for your actual Post.

---

**Below is the post for modified question:**

*In oracle you can try below query:*

```
select sum(count(rownum))
  from Table1
 group by "Name"
having count(*) = 1
```

OR

**[Here is SQLFiddel Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f578b/7)**

---

*In SQL Server you can try below query:*

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM Table1 a
  LEFT JOIN Table1 b 
    ON a.Name=b.Name 
   AND a.%%physloc%% <> b.%%physloc%%
 WHERE b.Name IS NULL
```

OR

**[Here is the SQLFiddel Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fd119/37)**

---

*In Sybase you can try below query:*

```
select count(count(name)) 
  from table 
 group by name 
having count(name) = 1
```

as per @user2617962's answer.

Thank you

Comment: Yes, Now i have modified

Comment: We need to be able to get the o/p without subquery.

Comment: That you are mentioning now.

Comment: Your first option worked for me - thanks!
Presumably the "T" at the end of the query adds an alias?

Answer (score 2):

```
   select count(*) from
      (select count(*) from Table1
       group by Name
       having count(*) =1) s
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84619/4)

Answer (score 0):

Since you just need the count of column values appearing once without the actual value of the column, the query should be:

> ```
> select count(count(name)) from table group by name having count(name)
> = 1
> ```

Comment: whats the error you are getting? The query is straight fwd, I tested the same and pasted above.

Comment: Sorry about that.. Actually I tested the query in sybase and pasted here. It worked in sybase, but not working for sql server. It seems you have already got the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try following.

```
select name from (select name, count(name) as num from tblUsers group by name)
tblTemp where tblTemp.num=1
```

Mark it if this works..:)